# How to programmatiacally set the Service Principal Name on a hosted service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-client, wcf-configuration

To do the above using the config file I would do:

```
<endpoint
  address="...."
  binding="netTcpBinding"
  bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"
  contract="IService1">
  <identity>
    <servicePrincipalName value="name"/>
  </identity>
</endpoint>
```

But how do I add it to the below code?

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/service");
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), uri);

NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, uri);
host.Open();
```

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit cumbersome, you need to use the return value of the AddServiceEndpoint method and set it there:

```
ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, uri);
EndpointAddress myEndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(uri, EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity("YourIdentity"));
serviceEndpoint.Address = myEndpointAddress;
```